# Inserting into multiple tables using SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code used to insert a new record into my database

```
DECLARE @CustomerID INT
DECLARE @PropertyID INT

BEGIN TRAN T1
    INSERT INTO c_customer (title, f_name, l_name, tel1, tel2, tel3, email, email2, 
                            type, primary_contact, tel1type, tel2type, tel3type) 
    VALUES(@title, @fname, @lname, @tel1, @tel2, @tel3, @email, @email2, 
           'Owner', 1, @teltype1, @teltype2, @teltype3)

    SET @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    BEGIN TRAN T2
        INSERT INTO c_property (address1, address2, address3, post_code, city, county) 
        VALUES (@address1, @address2, @address3, @postcode, @city, @county)

        SET @PropertyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        UPDATE c_property 
        SET invoice_flag = @PropertyID
        WHERE c_property = @PropertyID

        BEGIN TRAN T3

            INSERT INTO c_customer_assignment 
            VALUES (@PropertyID, @CustomerID)

            COMMIT TRAN T1
            COMMIT TRAN T2
            COMMIT TRAN T3

    SELECT @CustomerID, @PropertyID
```

This code works as I want it to, making sure that the added details are linked correctly using the `c_customer_assignment` table, however it does look overly complicated and I was wondering if I had taken the right approach to solving the problem (Not sure if I even need the nested transactions at all).

I know at least one transaction is needed, as I do need to make sure records don't get mismatched due to other users inserting at the same time.

Do I also need to review transaction isolation too, or is this enough?

Comment: if there is M-M relationship between  `c_customer` and `c_property`, then the 3 tables are required. you don't need 3 transactions. only 1 will do since any rollback will rollback all 3 nested transactions so you don't get any benefit for nested transactions.

Comment: So i could drop the extra 2 transactions? The table count isn't in question here. As you quite rightly stated, all 3 tables are needed due to a M-M relationship

Comment: the extra transactions don't add any benefit at all. check out http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/ and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @ughai Wonderful, that really explained things perfectly. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need one transaction:

```
DECLARE @CustomerID INT
DECLARE @PropertyID INT

BEGIN TRAN T1

    INSERT INTO c_customer (title, f_name, l_name, tel1, tel2, tel3, email, email2, type, primary_contact, tel1type, tel2type, tel3type) 
    VALUES(@title, @fname, @lname, @tel1, @tel2, @tel3, @email, @email2, 'Owner', 1, @teltype1, @teltype2, @teltype3)

    SET @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO c_property (address1, address2, address3, post_code, city, county) 
    VALUES (@address1, @address2, @address3, @postcode, @city, @county)

    SET @PropertyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE c_property 
    SET invoice_flag = @PropertyID
    WHERE c_property = @PropertyID

    INSERT INTO c_customer_assignment 
    VALUES (@PropertyID, @CustomerID)

    COMMIT TRAN T1

    SELECT @CustomerID, @PropertyID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use try catch instead of some many trasactions..

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY

---your dml operation should go here
---

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ---CATCH ERROR HERE AND ROLLBACK OPERATIONS HERE


    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Comment: There isn't any errors to catch. The code as it is works perfectly, but just seems a bit complicated.

Comment: then in catch rollback transaction instead of three transaction .